Product rule applying on operators
Let’s say we have a functional $\Gamma[A_t]$ with a function $A_t$ that depends on the variable $t$. Can we then simply perform the product rule on the operators if we want to compute
$$\partial_t\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta A_t}\Gamma[A_t]\right)= \partial_t\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta A_t}\right)\Gamma[A_t] + \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta A_t}\partial_t\Gamma[A_t]\right). $$
And how can we compute $\partial_t\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta A_t}\right) $?

@Abezhiko $\Gamma$ is the effective average action

You can apply the product rule indeed, but the unknown term vanishes actually, because the total derivative and the functional derivative commute. Let's consider a functional $F[x(t)] = F(t,x,\dot{x},\ldots)$. The chain rule permits to write both its differential as well as its functional differential, namely
$$
\mathrm{d}F = \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t + \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{x}}\mathrm{d}\dot{x} + \ldots
$$
and
$$
\delta F = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\delta x + \frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{x}}\delta\dot{x} + \ldots,
$$
so that the associated differentiating operators can be represented thanks to the chain rule as
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \dot{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \ddot{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{x}} + \ldots
$$
and
$$
\frac{\delta}{\delta x(\tau)} = \delta(t-\tau)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \delta'(t-\tau)\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{x}} + \ldots,
$$
where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta function. Now, the term you want to compute corresponds to the commutator of the two types of derivative above (by inverting your product rule), that is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta x(\tau)}\right) 
   &= \left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}, \frac{\delta}{\delta x(\tau)}\right] \\
   &= \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \sum_{n\in\Bbb{N}} x^{(n+1)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{(n)}}, \sum_{m\in\Bbb{N}} \delta^{(m)}(t-\tau)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{(m)}}\right] \\
   &= \sum_{m\in\Bbb{N}} \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}, \delta^{(m)}(t-\tau)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{(m)}}\right] + \sum_{n,m\in\Bbb{N}} \left[x^{(n+1)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{(n)}}, \delta^{(m)}(t-\tau)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{(m)}}\right] \\
   &= \sum_{m\in\Bbb{N}} \delta^{(m+1)}(t-\tau)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{(m)}} - \sum_{n,m\in\Bbb{N}} \delta_{n+1,m}\delta^{(m)}(t-\tau)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{(n)}} \\
   &= 0
\end{align}
$$
by bilinearity of the commutator, where $\delta_{nm}$ is the Kronecker delta.
